# Recording a sound looks ok but playing back doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, avaudioplayer, avaudiorecorder

The following code is supposed to record audio and then play it back. Everything is probably fine with recording, but it doesn't play back. Did anyone encounter the same problems or does anyone know what could I do to fix this code?

```
var filename="/audioFile.caf"
    var soundRecorder:AVAudioRecorder!
    var soundPlayer:AVAudioPlayer!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.setupRecorder()    }



    func setupRecorder() {
        let recordSettings = [AVSampleRateKey : NSNumber(float: Float(44100.0)),
            AVFormatIDKey : NSNumber(int: Int32(kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC)),
            AVNumberOfChannelsKey : NSNumber(int: 1),
            AVEncoderAudioQualityKey : NSNumber(int: Int32(AVAudioQuality.Medium.rawValue)),
            AVEncoderBitRateKey : NSNumber(int: Int32(320000))]
        var error:NSError?
        do {
        soundRecorder=try AVAudioRecorder(URL: getFileURL(), settings: recordSettings)
            soundRecorder.delegate=self
            soundRecorder.prepareToRecord()
        }
        catch {
        }
    }
    func getCacheDictionary() -> String {
        let paths=NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true) 
        return paths[0]
    }
    func getFileURL() -> NSURL {
        let path=getCacheDictionary().stringByAppendingString(filename)
        let filePath=NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path)
        return filePath
    }
    @IBAction func recordingButton(sender: UIButton) {
        soundRecorder.record()
    }

    @IBAction func Play(sender: AnyObject) {
        do {
        soundPlayer=try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: getFileURL())
            soundPlayer.delegate=self
            soundPlayer.prepareToPlay()
            soundPlayer.play()
        }
        catch {


        }
    }
    @IBAction func PauseRecording(sender: AnyObject) {
        soundRecorder.pause()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to stop the recorder (close the sound file) before playing.

in `@IBAction func Play(sender: AnyObject)`, ad this at the top:

```
soundRecoreder.stop()
```

This is from the abstract of the `stop` method from the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioRecorder_ClassReference/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/AVAudioRecorder/stop):

> Stops recording and closes the audio file.

Comment: thanks but it doesn't works , maybe we have problem with "recordSettings" ?